# Return custom response in logging middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make logging middleware, that logs (request, response in some cases, exceptions) and when an exception occurred, I want to return custom response.
currently, when an exception occurred, I cannot write to response body.
my code:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(
                context.Request.Body,
                encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
                bufferSize: 1024,
                leaveOpen: true))
            {
                strRequestBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            }

            var originalResponseBody = context.Response.Body;
            using var newResponseBody = new MemoryStream();
            context.Response.Body = newResponseBody;

            await _next(context);

            if (context.Response.StatusCode != 200)
            {
                newResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var jsonResponseBody = JObject.Parse(await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync());
                newResponseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await newResponseBody.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBody);

                _logger.LogInformation(
                    "HTTP {method} {url} => responded {statusCode}\n" +
                    "(response code: {responseCode}, response message: {message})\n" +
                    "Request query string: {queryString} \n" +
                    "Request body: {requestBody}",
                    context.Request?.Method,
                    context.Request?.Path.Value,
                    context.Response?.StatusCode,
                    jsonResponseBody["code"].ToString(),
                    jsonResponseBody["message"].ToString(),
                    context.Request?.QueryString.Value,
                    strRequestBody);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(
                    "HTTP {method} {url} => responded {statusCode} \n" +
                    "Request query string: {queryString} \n" +
                    "Request body: {requestBody}",
                    context.Request?.Method,
                    context.Request?.Path.Value,
                    context.Response?.StatusCode,
                    context.Request?.QueryString.Value,
                    strRequestBody);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                BaseResponse.Failed(500, "Somthing went wrong."));
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonResponse, Encoding.UTF8);

            _logger.LogError(
                    "HTTP {method} {url} => responded {statusCode} \n" +
                    "Request query string: {queryString} \n" +
                    "Request body: {requestBody} \n" +
                    "Error: {error}",
                    context.Request?.Method,
                    context.Request?.Path.Value,
                    context.Response?.StatusCode,
                    context.Request?.QueryString.Value,
                    strRequestBody,
                    "Exception message: " + ex.Message + "\n" +
                    "Exception stacktrace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\n" +
                    "Inner exception message: " + ex.InnerException?.Message + "\n" +
                    "Inner exception stacktrace: " + ex.InnerException?.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

in the (catch) block, this line:

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonResponse, Encoding.UTF8);
```

throws this exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
```

**my question**: how can I return custom response from middleware in case exception occurred?
thanks in advance,

Comment: i think this is bad context.Response.Body = newResponseBody;

Answer (score 0):

the response body is non-readable stream, so you need to assign a readable stream to the body in order to read it, these lines:

```
var originalResponseBody = context.Response.Body;
using var newResponseBody = new MemoryStream();
context.Response.Body = newResponseBody;
```

we assigned MemoryStream to the response body before **await _next(context)**.
when **await _next(context)** is called and an exception occurred in the pipeline, the execution goes to (catch) block, here we need to restore the response body back to its original stream before writing to it in the (catch) block (first line):

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Body = originalResponseBody;
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                BaseResponse.Failed(500, "Somthing went wrong."));
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonResponse, Encoding.UTF8);

            _logger.LogError(
                    "HTTP {method} {url} => responded {statusCode} \n" +
                    "Request query string: {queryString} \n" +
                    "Request body: {requestBody} \n" +
                    "Error: {error}",
                    context.Request?.Method,
                    context.Request?.Path.Value,
                    context.Response?.StatusCode,
                    context.Request?.QueryString.Value,
                    strRequestBody,
                    "Exception message: " + ex.Message + "\n" +
                    "Exception stacktrace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\n" +
                    "Inner exception message: " + ex.InnerException?.Message + "\n" +
                    "Inner exception stacktrace: " + ex.InnerException?.StackTrace);
        }
```